# Error pages in expresso store?

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, error-pages, system-messages

Looking to be able to style/customize error pages for Expresso Store or EE.
Anyone have experience ideas of this please?
Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful replies!

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as correct if it solves your question

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to customize the error messages shown would be to set `error_handling=”inline”` in your checkout template opening tag as mentioned in the docs [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/tags/checkout.html#error-handling-inline). Then you would be able to add `{error:field_name}` anywhere you would like to show the errors.

Alternatively if you want to customize the text that is shown you can do something like:

`{if error:field_name}Whoa buddy! Your custom error message for this field_name goes here.{/if}`

If that doesn't fit your needs you would need to use something like Custom System Messages of LibrarEE or redoing the built in error templates to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if Store has it's own error pages or not though, for EE itself take a look at Custom System Messages for styling all your error pages:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages

Answer (score 3):

You can control the page EE shows when a 404 is encountered via your [Global Template Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#page).

The error page you see when EE or an add-on encounters a submission error, or when you're being redirected after a form submission, is controlled via the [User Message Template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/message_pages/index.html#user-message-template).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your error code i.e. `{error:field_name}` in a label tag and then style your label tag with some css. This ought to do the trick.

Something like:

```
<label class="error">{error:field_name}</label>
```