# Store custom errors not working

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to use field:billing_name error:order_custom1 to generate the error message I've set in Settings > Order Fields > order_custom1 - but the message is not displayed when the field on the front end is left empty.

I have error_handling="inline" and require="name" set in exp:store:checkout. If it makes any difference I'm using membership on the site.

Have I missed something out?

Thanks!
Lee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping in Settings >> Order Fields >> order_custom1 would be more for you then the error messages. For example you might have Gender in your template you would want to have something along the lines of:

```
{field:order_custom1}
{if error:order_custom1}Whoa you need to select Male or Female{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. So I can't change/customise the default error messages?

Comment: Found my answer: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/622/error-pages-in-expresso-store